# Nofollow links between sites owned by same company

Tags: nofollow

My company owns 2 websites with the following characteristics:

- Same categorization and URL structure
- The inventories are entirely disjoint

[Site #1](http://www.BandagedEar.com) concentrates on reproductions of famous oil paintings.
[Site #2](http://www.PosterNation.com) concentrates on posters/photographs.

Site #1 promotes Site #2 and vice-versa. Currently, these links are `nofollow`. I am concerned over what could look like over-optimization. Is it the right approach?

Here is what the first page for Florida looks like on Site #1:

```
http://www.bandagedear.com/category/places/united-states/florida
```

You will find thumbnail links to Site #2 near the bottom of the page. The same principle applies to Site #2:

```
http://www.posternation.com/category/places/united-states/florida
```

**Should we use nofollow links like we do today?**

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why you need to use `nofollow` here. Google's examples for using `nofollow` ([link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569)) are:

> - Untrusted content
> - Paid links
> - Crawl prioritization

However I can see your thinking behind wanting to use them; your sites are similar in subject and structure. However, linking between your own sites is not a violation of Google guidelines and they say it makes perfect sense; unless you have many, many sites, all on the same subject, which could look like a link network.

Here is a recent video from Matt Cutts on this exact subject:
[Does linking my two sites together violate the quality guidelines?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0-jw_PfwtY)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above poster, but I would use something like `rel="me"`. Should be easy to code into the site. At worst it does nothing, at best it at least mitigates the risk of being perceived as a link network.